# Detect distance scrolled in vh JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simple question. I have a vh section based website, with certain functions that I want to take place once a certain vh has been scrolled. I know how to get this distance in pixels, but haven't found any way to get the vh. How can I do this?

Comment: you can divide the pixels by the viewport height

Answer (score 1):

To get the `vh` equivalent of scroll height `sHpx` in  `px`

```
function getVh(sHpx) {
  $windowH = $(window).height(); 
  $vh = $windowH*0.01;
  return (sHpx / $vh);
}
```